# How to create a Tags collection and a Categories collection in Eleventy

Tags: eleventy

I have the following two blocks of code in my `.eleventy.js` file

```
    // Tags
    eleventyConfig.addCollection('tagList', collection => {
        const tagsSet = new Set();
        collection.getAll().forEach(item => {
            if (!item.data.tags) return;
            item.data.tags.filter(tag => !['posts', 'all'].includes(tag)).forEach(tag => tagsSet.add(tag));
        });
        return Array.from(tagsSet).sort();
    });

    // Categories
    eleventyConfig.addCollection('categoryList', collection => {
        let catSet = new Set();
        collection.getAll().forEach(item => {
            if (!item.data.categories) return;
            item.data.categories.filter(cat => !['posts', 'all'].includes(cat)).forEach(cat => catSet.add(cat));
        });
        return Array.from(catSet).sort();
    });
```

In my posts I Have

```
---
layout: post
title: 'Whatever'
date: '2021-10-12'
permalink: '{{ title | slug }}/index.html'
categories:
    - code
tags:
    - javascript
    - angular
---
```

And i'm using a template like this to auto generate pages for each Tag (and a similar one for categories).

```
---
layout: page
eleventyComputed:
    title: All posts tagged '{{ tag }}'
    permalink: /tags/{{ tag }}/
pagination:
    data: collections
    size: 1
    alias: tag
    filter:
        - all
        - nav
        - post
        - posts
        - tagList
    addAllPagesToCollections: true
permalink: /tags/{{ tag }}/
headerButton:
    url: '/blog/'
    text: All posts
---

<ul class="unstyled">
    {%- for post in collections[tag].reverse() -%}
    {%- if not post.data.draft -%}
    <li>{% include 'post-listing.njk' %}</li>
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

For tags, everything is working fine. I get the correct pages generated i.e. `/tags/javascript` but for categories, its generating pages based on the Tags and not the categories. So instead of `/categories/code` I'm ending up with `/categories/javascript`

I'm assuming the issue is with my `eleventyConfig.addCollection('categoryList')` function but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be in the pagination in your template. You're paginating on the [`collections` object](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/), which is an object mapping tags (a special 11ty front matter attribute) to pages with that tag.

Since you're creating a list of tags and categories as collection items, you'll want to paginate that collection instead.

```yaml
---
# ...
pagination:
    data: collections.tagList # (or collections.categoryList)
    size: 1
    alias: tag
    # ...
---
```

This might pose an issue since you're accessing the posts themselves in the template, so you need a way to map the tag/category back to the list of posts. You can fix this by changing your collections to an `Object` instead of an `Array`.

```js
    // Tags
    eleventyConfig.addCollection('tagList', collection => {
        const tagsSet = {};
        collection.getAll().forEach(item => {
            if (!item.data.tags) return;
            item.data.tags.filter(
                tag => !['posts', 'all'].includes(tag)
            ).forEach(
                tag => {
                    if (!tagsSet[tag]) { tagsSet[tag] = []; }
                    tagsSet[tag].push(item)
                }
            );
        });
        return tagsSet;
    });

    // Categories
    eleventyConfig.addCollection('categoryList', collection => {
        let catSet = {};
        collection.getAll().forEach(item => {
            if (!item.data.categories) return;
            item.data.categories.filter(
                cat => !['posts', 'all'].includes(cat)
            ).forEach(
                cat => {
                    if (!catSet[cat]) { catSet[cat] = []; }
                    catSet[cat].push(item)
                }
            );
        });
        return catSet;
    });
```

Now, when you want to access the posts, you can index into `collections.tagList` (or `collections.categoryList`).

```
{%- for post in collections.tagList[tag] | reverse -%}
```

Comment: Thanks. For the most part this answered my query, but see my response for another issue its caused https://stackoverflow.com/a/72198520/1551819

Answer (score 0):

Everything you suggested above has worked. I now have separate pages for tags and categories generated, so thank you for that.

The issue I now have is, on my Blog page, i previously had a list of Tags being output like so

```
<div class="tags tags--buttons">
  {%- for tag in collections.tagList -%}
    <a href="/tags/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>
  {%- endfor -%}
</div>
```

This no longer outputs anything since the collection is no longer an array.

I updated to

```
<div class="tags tags--buttons">
  {%- for tag, val in collections.tagList -%}
    <a href="/tags/{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>
  {%- endfor -%}
</div>
```

and this works fine for Tags, but its not working for collections (using `collections.categoryList`)

Also, the tags are no longer in alphabetical order

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

The code for outputting categories is

```
    {%- for cat, val in collections.categoryList | dictsort -%}
        {%- if cat !== "posts" -%}
            <a href="/categories/{{cat}}">{{cat}}</a>
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

This doesn't give any errors, but also no output.
If I add `| dictsort` to it, then I get the error `Template render error: dictsort filter: val must be an object`

Comment: For sorting, you can use the [`dictsort` filter](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#dictsort), but I'm not sure why categories wouldn't work. Could you share your categories code?

Comment: I'm basically doing the exact same as tags. Have edited my question above.

Comment: Ah, looks like it was a mistake in my code: `catSet` should be initialized to an empty object `{}` instead of a `new Set()`. I forgot to change this; my bad! I've updated the example in my answer.